# Does "use" require a \backslash prefix when importing namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

Both works just fine:

`use \Vendor\Package\Foo;`

`use Vendor\Package\Foo;`

---

But I always use `\` prefix in inline namespace declarations (so it starts in the root namespace) e.g.:

```
function Bar ()
{
    return \Vendor\Package\Foo();
}
```

What's the proper way to use `use` when importing namespace, with `\` prefix or without?

Comment: Is there a difference in speed using either implementation, I mean \Vendor\Package\Foo vs Vendor\Package\Foo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `use` statements used for imports `\` prefix is unnecessary. `\` prefix is only needed when you're in namespaced context and you want to use namespace not relative to current namespace (for example using class from global namespace). Imports always expecting FQN and they're never relative to current namespace:

> Note that for namespaced names (fully qualified namespace names containing namespace separator, such as `Foo\Bar` as opposed to global names that do not, such as `FooBar`), the leading backslash is unnecessary and not recommended, as import names must be fully qualified, and are not processed relative to the current namespace.
>
> <sub>http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php</sub>